# Android 5 ADB notification dump wrong data

Tags: android, debugging, notifications, adb

I built a pc program that works on your desktop and informs you about notifications, power-level, and lets you interact with your smartphone.
All over the ADB - so no app on the phone is required.
And all that in a stylish way.

But enough for that, it worked until android 5 came along.

The notification dump (adb shell dumpsys notifications) shows different outputs than in sdk <= 19

For example:

The extras region showed me detailed informations about the notifications.

```cs
      extras={
        android.title=String
        android.subText=null
        android.template=String
        android.showChronometer=Boolean (false)
        android.icon=Integer (2130837507)
        android.text=String
        android.progress=Integer (0)
        android.progressMax=Integer (0)
        android.showWhen=Boolean (true)
        android.rebuild.applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo (ApplicationInfo{14a2c165 com.nero.android.htc.sync})
        android.rebuild.contentView=Boolean (true)
        android.bigText=String
        android.infoText=null
        android.originatingUserId=Integer (0)
        android.progressIndeterminate=Boolean (false)
        android.rebuild=Boolean (true)
        android.rebuild.bigView=Boolean (true)
      }
```

This is an example of the android 5 Notification dump.
You see, there are only datatypes for strings, not the actual values.

Does anybody know how i can get the actual values? Like some parameters i am missing?

Or do you know an even better way of getting the notifications from the phone to the pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I faced the same problem and it seems it has no solution.

I've looked at the source code and compared it to the version when everything was working.
In the version 4.4.4 it was still working. Changes appeared in the version 5.0.0 and the code wasn't changed to the version 5.1.1 (the last source code version we have on the moment I'm writing this post).

So, lets look at the source code that responsible for printing extra section of notification.

***As you see, it's everything ok in Android 4.4.4, the code prints string representation of the value.
In Android 5.0.0 - 5.1.1 it prints only a type of value, but not the value itself.***

**Android 4.4.4.**

```
if (notification.extras != null && notification.extras.size() > 0) {
    pw.println(prefix + "  extras={");
    for (String key : notification.extras.keySet()) {
        pw.print(prefix + "    " + key + "="); // <====== print key name
        Object val = notification.extras.get(key);
        if (val == null) {
            pw.println("null");
        } else {
            pw.print(val.toString()); // <====== print value here
            if (val instanceof Bitmap) {
                pw.print(String.format(" (%dx%d)",
                        ((Bitmap) val).getWidth(),
                        ((Bitmap) val).getHeight()));
            } else if (val.getClass().isArray()) {
                pw.println(" {");
                final int N = Array.getLength(val);
                for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                    if (i > 0) pw.println(",");
                    pw.print(prefix + "      " + Array.get(val, i));
                }
                pw.print("\n" + prefix + "    }");
            }
            pw.println();
        }
    }
    pw.println(prefix + "  }");
}
```

**Android 5.0.0 - 5.1.1.**

```
if (notification.extras != null && notification.extras.size() > 0) {
    pw.println(prefix + "  extras={");
    for (String key : notification.extras.keySet()) {
        pw.print(prefix + "    " + key + "="); // <====== print key name
        Object val = notification.extras.get(key);
        if (val == null) {
            pw.println("null");
        } else {
            pw.print(val.getClass().getSimpleName()); // <===== print a type, not a value itself
            if (val instanceof CharSequence || val instanceof String) {
                // redact contents from bugreports
            } else if (val instanceof Bitmap) {
                pw.print(String.format(" (%dx%d)",
                        ((Bitmap) val).getWidth(),
                        ((Bitmap) val).getHeight()));
            } else if (val.getClass().isArray()) {
                final int N = Array.getLength(val);
                pw.println(" (" + N + ")");
            } else {
                pw.print(" (" + String.valueOf(val) + ")");
            }
            pw.println();
        }
    }
    pw.println(prefix + "  }");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android >= 6 use this command to get full text of notification extras:

```sh
adb shell dumpsys notification --noredact
```

it will print both types and values

```
      extras={
          android.title=String (Bring The Rain)
          android.reduced.images=Boolean (true)
          android.subText=null
          android.template=String (android.app.Notification$MediaStyle)
          toSingleLine=Boolean (false)
          android.text=String (Upon A Burning Body)
          android.appInfo=ApplicationInfo (ApplicationInfo{c8165e6 org.telegram.messenger})
          android.showWhen=Boolean (false)
          android.largeIcon=Icon (Icon(typ=BITMAP size=100x100))
          android.mediaSession=Token (android.media.session.MediaSession$Token@608a746)
          gameDndOn=Boolean (false)
          android.compactActions=int[] (3)
            [0] 0
            [1] 1
            [2] 2
      }
```