# How to get all notifications over ADB (Android 5)

Tags: android, notifications, adb

I have a program that uses the ADB bridge to control an android phone and read its values (Battery etc.)

How can i get a list of notifications and their content over ADB? Is it possible?

FYI this was asked by me before [Android 5 ADB notification dump wrong data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673899/android-5-adb-notification-dump-wrong-data)
The Data is just not as present as i need it anymore!

Comment: Doesn't really anyone know this on the internet?

Comment: Have you tried `adb logcat -b events`?

Comment: You are not permitted to re-post questions.  Besides, your original is a much better statement of the problem.  I strongly suspect you will find that you cannot get the information you want any more, but the best way to research it would be to identify the relevant parts of the Android source code (what you are seeing is probably mostly from AOSP, not vendor changes) and look at how they have changed between versions.

Comment: I cant search android source codes. And people that can could have a look into it.

If i could look into the sourcecode and understand it, i wouldnt ask here....!